# Reformatting the pattern inside a list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, pattern-matching

So, in principle, I have a simple problem which goes like this:
I have vectors that should consist of lists of 2 numbers, see here:

```
vector1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1198, 800}, {1199 799}, {1200, 799}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}};
```

Unfortunately, sometimes they do not have this structure, but are mixed like in here, where the parenthesis are missing around 1200,800 and the following 0,0:

```
vector2 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 1200, 800, 0, 0, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}};
```

My current solution is to use While with If inside, to create a new list with the correct structure:

```
correctVectorPattern[inputVector_] :=
Module[{i = 1, newVector = {}},
    While[i <= Length[inputVector],
      If[Length[inputVector[[i]]] ==2, {AppendTo[newVector,inputVector[[i]]],i++}, {AppendTo[newVector, {inputVector[[i]], inputVector[[i + 1]]}], i = i + 2}]
    ];
    newVector
]
```

It gives me what I want:

```
In[39]:= correctVectorPattern[vector1]
Out[39]= {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1198, 800}, {1199,799}, {1200, 799}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}

In[36]:= correctVectorPattern[vector2]
Out[36]= {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1200, 800}, {0,0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

But I can't shake off the feeling that my solution is far from the capabilities of Mma regarding pattern matchin in expressions. Also, I am using If, While and AppendTo, which are probably not the fastest functions for solving my problem. Unfortunately, the vectors are at least 1200 elements long and I need to process 800 of them (these dimensions are due to the size of images I get the vectors from  - of 1200 x 800).
On my machine it takes me about 14 s, which is not that long, but I would like to scale it up to 5000 x 3000 pixels. 
Of course Parallel processig or Compiling are also possible and easy options, but with Mma pattern capabilities - shouldn't the solution be something of a 1-liner?

I tried of course myself to solve problem by exploiting patterns, but I end up processing all of the elements in the same way.
So I simply don't know how to tell MMa to group elements inside the list that are whithout parenthesises into 2-tuples, while keeping the other 2-tuples..

Does somebody have a more elegant or faster solution to my problem? Thanks a lot!

(And should you wonder why I ask, even though I have working solution: .. a better understanding of Mma doesn't hurt at all ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 Partition[Developer`ToPackedArray[Flatten[vector2]], 2]
```

`` Developer`ToPackedArray `` guarantees that you have a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496) in the end that is much more efficient to work with.

But it would be more efficient to never let such ragged lists appear in numerical computations.

By the way: Using patterns is usually not a good way to speed up computations: pattern matching takes time that can be saved by guaranteeing that your input can be processed blindly by vectorized routines.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thanks a lot, that is exactly what I wanted :)      But: I get 2 Outputs: ony is a string "ry" and the other is the vector. WHat is the significance of the "ry" and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Well, it is Sunday and I am lying in wait for a good question here ;)

Comment: Sorry, forget about the ry - I was too enthusiastic typing it in my front end and I acidentally copied the last two letters form your "Try" in front of the expresssion...

Comment: No problem. Actually, I overlooked the "ry". ^^